# Specify node priority for a job

Tags: slurm

I'm want to make a 'soft' request of specific nodes. For example, I would prefer my job to be executed on either Node1 or Node2, but if they are not available than I would settle for Node3 or Node4 (the job is running on one node only). The request has to be per job, and not just setting the nodes priority for the whole cluster.

Can it be done? I did not find any flag that can do that so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do that with Slurm. Here is a convoluted procedure that should work.

The idea is to submit two jobs:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --exclude Node1,Node2
#SBATCH --name convolutedproc
#SBATCH --dependency singleton
#SBATCH --nice 1000

scancel --name convolutedproc --state PENDING

#Useful work here
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --exclude Node3,Node4
#SBATCH --name convolutedproc
#SBATCH --dependency singleton
#SBATCH --nice 0

scancel --name convolutedproc --state PENDING

#Useful work here
```

The first job to start kills the other. Slurm makes sure not to start both at the same time with `singleton`, and if they are both eligible at the same time, the one with `--nice 0` will be chosen first.